# Reading tabular data from pdf file

Tags: python, file, pdf

I am trying to read numerical data from a table as a string in python. (I have tried many different ways to convert the table to CSV, Excel and so on but nothing seems to work perfectly. Therefore I wanna try the string approach)
Each line looks basically like this:

```
"ebit 34 894 38 445 28 013 26 356 12 387 -8 680 -2 760 838"
```

Here we have 8 columns. The last digits to the right: 838 belongs to one column, -2 760 belongs to one column, 12 387 belongs to one column, and so on. Does anyone have a smart approach on how to know which numbers belong to which column?

Comment: Can you provide the example of pdf file

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Is there a difference between how -2768 -8 760 and -2 768  -8760 would be written?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @hotten If I have the numbers [-2768, -8, 760] this would be written as '-2 768 -8 760'. If I have the numbers[ -2, 768, -8760] this would be written as '-2 768 -8 760' right? What is the difference in output between the first and second set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to solve this exactly without access to your actual data, but basically you need to parse your PDF table using something other than copy-paste, since that is causing confusion between **inter-column spacing** and **spaces used as a thousands separator**.

So for a start I'd recommend something like [Xpdf tools](http://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html) which is a set of command-line utilities for parsing PDF documents. One of the utilities is called `pdftotext.exe` which I've tested on a [sample PDF file](https://www.intrum.com/globalassets/corporate/ir/presentations/intrum_q317_presentation.pdf) called `intrum_q317_presentation.pdf`

So for example, to extract the table on page 17 of this document:

[image]

You might run this command:

```
C:\Program Files\xpdf-tools-win-4.00\bin64\pdftotext.exe" -table -f 17 -l 17 intrum_q317_presentation.pdf parsed_output.txt
```

Which produces this output (in `parsed_output.txt`):

```
Cash flow statement

                                                                  Q3   Q3    Dev    YTD     YTD     Dev

SEK M                                                         2017     2016  %      2017    2016    %

Operating earnings (EBIT)                                         977  506   93     1 921   1 379   39

Depreciation                                                      163  40    308    245     120     104

Amortization and revaluation of purchased debt                    866  389   123    1 845   1 137   62

Income tax paid                                                   -97  -33   194    -283    -187    51

Changes in factoring receivables                                  7    -25   -128   -39     -45     -13

Other changes in working capital                                  5    -60   -108   -8      -119    n/a

Financial net & other non-cash items                          -125     -6    1983   -486    -74     557

Cash flow from operating activities (CFFO)                    1 796    811   121    3 195   2 211   45

Purchases of tangible and intangible fixed assets (CAPEX)         -38  -33   15     -115    -103    12

Purchases of debt                                             -1  124  -732  54     -4 317  -2 188  97

Purchases of shares in subsidiaries and associated companies      -2   -1    100    -171    -89     92

Liquid assets in acquired subsidiaries                            0    0            975     1

Other cash flow form investing activities                         -1   2     -150   -2      6       -133

Cash flow from investing activities (CFFI)                    -1  165  -764  52     -3 630  -2 373  53

Cash flow from investing activities (CFFI)

excl liquid assets in acquired subsidiaries                   -1  165  -764  52     -4 605  -2 374  94

Free cash flow (CFFO - CFFI)                                      631  47    1 243  -435    -167    160

Free cash flow (CFFO - CFFI) excl liquid

assets in acquired subsidiaries                                   631  47    1 243  -1 410  -168    739

                                                                                                17
```

You can see this is quite like your string, but with wider spacing between the individual columns.

Then we can use some python to parse this into a 2-dimensional array:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import re

template = ''

with open('C:\\parsed_output.txt') as f:
    raw_lines = [line for line in f.readlines() if line.strip() != '']
    lines = raw_lines[1:-1] # ignore first and last lines
    for raw_line in lines:
        length = max([len(template), len(raw_line)])
        old_template = template.ljust(length)
        line = raw_line.ljust(length)
        template = ''
        for i in range(0,length):
            template += ' ' if (old_template[i]==' ' and line[i]==' ') else 'X'

# try to work out the column widths, based on alignment of spaces:
column_widths = [len(x) for x in template.split()]
column_count = len(column_widths)
column_starts = [0]
start = 0
for i in range(1, column_count):
    start = template.find(' X',start) + 1
    column_starts.append(start)
column_starts.append(len(template)) # add final value to terminate right-most column

# now divide up each line using our column widths
rows=[]
for raw_line in lines:
    line = raw_line.ljust(len(template))
    row=[]
    for i in range(0, column_count):
        value = line[column_starts[i]:column_starts[i+1]].strip()
        if i>0: value = re.sub('\s+', '', value)
        row.append(value)
    rows.append(row)

print(tabulate(rows, tablefmt='grid'))
```

... which gives the following result:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
|                                                              | Q3    | Q3   | Dev  | YTD   | YTD   | Dev  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| SEK M                                                        | 2017  | 2016 | %    | 2017  | 2016  | %    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Operating earnings (EBIT)                                    | 977   | 506  | 93   | 1921  | 1379  | 39   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Depreciation                                                 | 163   | 40   | 308  | 245   | 120   | 104  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Amortization and revaluation of purchased debt               | 866   | 389  | 123  | 1845  | 1137  | 62   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Income tax paid                                              | -97   | -33  | 194  | -283  | -187  | 51   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Changes in factoring receivables                             | 7     | -25  | -128 | -39   | -45   | -13  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Other changes in working capital                             | 5     | -60  | -108 | -8    | -119  | n/a  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Financial net & other non-cash items                         | -125  | -6   | 1983 | -486  | -74   | 557  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Cash flow from operating activities (CFFO)                   | 1796  | 811  | 121  | 3195  | 2211  | 45   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Purchases of tangible and intangible fixed assets (CAPEX)    | -38   | -33  | 15   | -115  | -103  | 12   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Purchases of debt                                            | -1124 | -732 | 54   | -4317 | -2188 | 97   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Purchases of shares in subsidiaries and associated companies | -2    | -1   | 100  | -171  | -89   | 92   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Liquid assets in acquired subsidiaries                       | 0     | 0    |      | 975   | 1     |      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Other cash flow form investing activities                    | -1    | 2    | -150 | -2    | 6     | -133 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Cash flow from investing activities (CFFI)                   | -1165 | -764 | 52   | -3630 | -2373 | 53   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Cash flow from investing activities (CFFI)                   |       |      |      |       |       |      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| excl liquid assets in acquired subsidiaries                  | -1165 | -764 | 52   | -4605 | -2374 | 94   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Free cash flow (CFFO - CFFI)                                 | 631   | 47   | 1243 | -435  | -167  | 160  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| Free cash flow (CFFO - CFFI) excl liquid                     |       |      |      |       |       |      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
| assets in acquired subsidiaries                              | 631   | 47   | 1243 | -1410 | -168  | 739  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+------+
```

Of course, it's not perfect (eg 'Q3 2017' should be in one cell), and it's not guaranteed to work with your exact data (you might need to manually tweak the column widths for example), but it should get you started.

Comment: The problem is that I have 15 numbers in this certain case and 8 columns. The last value is 838. I am gonna read thousands of rows that look like this. So the number of values can range between [8,16]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This seems like the best possible option